# Getting values for an enum?

Tags: php, enums

I have an enum:

```
enum Type: int
{
    case OFFENSIVE = 1;
    case SPAM = 2;
    case IRRELEVANT = 3;
}
```

I understand I can get all types and their values with `Type::cases()`, but how can I just get the values (1,2,3) for an enum?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`cases()` returns the individual enum objects; getting their associated values is a case of looking at `->value` on each one. In full:

```
$values = [];
foreach ( Type::cases() as $case ) {
    $values[] = $case->value;
}
```

Fortunately, there is a [built-in function `array_column`](https://php.net/array_column) which basically performs this loop for you:

```
$values = array_column(Type::cases(), 'value');
```

You can also specify what you want to be the *key* of the resulting array, so lots of variations are possible depending what you need:

```
$enum_objects_as_list = Type::cases();
// [Type::OFFENSIVE, Type::SPAM, Type::IRRELEVANT]

$values_as_list = array_column(Type::cases(), 'value');
// [1, 2, 3]

$names_as_list = array_column(Type::cases(), 'name');
// ['OFFENSIVE', 'SPAM', 'IRRELEVANT']

$name_to_value_lookup = array_column(Type::cases(), 'value', 'name');
// ['OFFENSIVE' => 1, 'SPAM' => 2, 'IRRELEVANT' => 3]

$value_to_name_lookup = array_column(Type::cases(), 'name', 'value');
// [1 => 'OFFENSIVE', 2 => 'SPAM', 3 => 'IRRELEVANT']

$name_to_enum_object_lookup = array_column(Type::cases(), null, 'name');
// ['OFFENSIVE' => Type::OFFENSIVE, 'SPAM' => Type::SPAM, 'IRRELEVANT' => Type::IRRELEVANT]

$value_to_enum_object_lookup = array_column(Type::cases(), null, 'value');
// [1 => Type::OFFENSIVE, 2 => Type::SPAM, 3 => Type::IRRELEVANT]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `array_map`:

```
$values = array_map(fn($i) => $i->value, Type::cases());
```

Answer (score 1):

If the enum type was declared like this:

```
enum Type: int { 
    ...
}
```

this implicitly uses the \IntBackedEnum interface implementation
and thus it is possible to directly refer to its value by:

```
Type::SPAM->value
```

Comment: Ahhh! Yes - exactly what I was looking for (sometimes it seems these things should be at least 'semi' obvious..?)