# How to get Enum values Array in PHP

Tags: php, enums, php-8

I have Enum Class.

```
<?php

namespace Enum;


enum Status:string
{
    case ACTIVE = 'active';
    case ARCHIVE = 'archive';
    case INACTIVE = 'inactive';
}
```

I'd like to retrieve values as array like this. `['active', 'archive', 'inactive']`.

Can anyone please help me how I can get this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting values for an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71235907/getting-values-for-an-enum)